# How to Bind keyup event to jqGrid Edit Cell to Auto Move to new Row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using free jqGrid 4.13.3. I use inline editing of one column. After changing the value of the column cell and pressing the enter key I would like to fire a function to move to the next row in edit mode ready to be changed.

I have tried the following but the event does not seem to fire.

```
function oSelect(id){
        selID = id;
        $("#ifetestdetailslist").setColProp('reading', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'keyup', fn: function(e) {if(event.keyCode=='13'){readingchange();  }}}]}});

        if(id && id!==lastsel){
            $("#ifetestdetailslist").jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);

            $("#ifetestdetailslist").jqGrid('editRow', id, {
                keys: true,
                focusField: 'reading',
                oneditfunc: function (rowid, options) {
                    $control = $("#" + rowid + "_reading");
                    if ($control.length > 0) {
                        $control[0].select();
                    }
                }
            });

            lastsel=id;
        }           
    };
```

Comment: Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Am I missing something here? I need help to get this resolved if what I am trying to do is even possible.